# Using prop as class name with React + Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a simple React component that is supposed to take a `status` prop. The value of which can be `initialized`, `connected` or `disconnected`

Based on the value of this prop, I would like to add a CSS class with the same name, whilst using material-UI styles.

I've got something like this, which gives the element the class name, but it doesn't match up with the class name that's been generated by MaterialUI

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const styles = {
  root: {
    height: '2px'
  },
  initialized: {
    backgroundColor: 'orange'
  },
  connected: {
    backgroundColor: 'green'
  },
  disconnected: {
    backgroundColor: 'red'
  }
};

class CableStatus extends React.PureComponent {
  render() {
    const { classes, status } = this.props;

    return (
      <div className={classes.root + ' ' + status}>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

CableStatus.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default withStyles(styles)(CableStatus);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should set the desired class like this:

```
let statusClass = classes[status];
<div className={`${classes.root} ${statusClass}`}></div>
```

Comment: Does it work when using double-quotes. I think you should use Template strings. It should be:
```<div className={`${classes.root} ${statusClass}`}></div>```

Answer (score 2):

When you want to use mutiple classes in Material UI. There are 2 ways:

```
let statusClass = classes[status]
<div className={`${classes.root} ${statusClass}`}></div>
```

```
import clsx from 'clsx'
...
let statusClass = classes[status]
<div className={clsx(classes.root, statusClass)}></div>
```